# Would it be necessary for ios webview to use https when Apple requiring mandatory use of https?

Tags: ios, webview, https, app-transport-security

Current situation:

1. Not long ago, Apple delayed the mandatory use of https
2. Our app that
   has been released, not fully forced to use https. Because some
   requests in webView do not support https yet.

Questions:

1. If the requirement  of using  https  was necessary, then  could  I
   still use http in webView by setting the “Allow Arbitrary Loads in
   Web Content” as “YES” and setting the “Allow Arbitrary Loads”  as
   “NO”?
2. In addition,  would the requirement impact the app that has
   been released already?

Comment: You can add exception domains to your info.plist, so just add them in there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UIWebViews or WKWebViews, you could use the `NSAllowsArbitrartyLoadsInWebContent` exception to allow any http connection in your webviews. However, note that this would only help for devices running iOS 10 and greater. If your app supports iOS9, and you only include the web content exception, iOS 9 users will not be able to load sites that use http.  In order to support both, Apple has a combination where you set **both** `NSAllowsArbitrartyLoadsInWebContent` **and** `NSAllowsArbitrartyLoads` in your Info.plist.  This will basically disable App Transport Security (ATS) on iOS 9 devices, but in iOS 10, the `NSAllowsArbitrartyLoadsInWebContent` setting will override the `NSAllowsArbitrartyLoads` setting, meaning http and non-ATS compliant connections will only be allowed in WebViews.

I would recommend that if you allow the user to do web browsing to arbitrary sites within your app, you should consider switching to SFSafariViewController.  It does not require any ATS exceptions, because it is essentially embedding Safari within your app, but as a separate process. If you can't control the sites your users can go to, it provides flexibility while giving them the best experience.

As for apps already in the store:  if the app was compiled with a base SDK prior to iOS 9, the ATS protections would not have been baked in. The app should run fine on iOS 9 and iOS 10.  You can confirm by installing the app from the App Store on an iOS 9 or 10 device and confirming you can hit http:// URLs.

Just understand that Apple did not delay the requirement for using https - ATS is active on devices running iOS 9 and up, for apps that were compiled with iOS9 or greater base SDK.  What they delayed was the need to provide justification when using the `NSAllowArbitraryLoads` exception.  That check is done when you submit the app to Apple.  No existing apps in the store will be affected, it's just that if you need one of the exceptions listed above, you will need to have a reason for disabling aspects of ATS.  If your current app in the store is using the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` exception, you have disabled ATS for your app and at some point, Apple is going to want you to explain why you are potentially putting your users at risk by doing insecure communications with servers.